# Get specific user information like email, firstname, etc other than sub attribute from userinfo endpoint of ADFS 2016

Tags: active-directory, adfs, liferay

I am trying to authenticate the user with ADFS is identity provider and liferay is service provider.

To authenticate, I'm using openid connect as SSO which is already existed in liferay 7.3.5 CE GA6.

What I did to set up openid connect: I filled the SSO form that has authorization, token, userinfo endpoint, jwks_uri, issuer, subject type and scope with values are openid, profile, email.

About the discovery endpoint, I left it blank. The information I filled is from `***/.well-known/openid-configuration`. And the ADFS is also configured to accept openid connect.

Problem that I met:

```
ERROR [https-jsse-nio-9595-exec-1][status_jsp:861] Unable to map OpenId Connect user to the portal, missing or invalid profile information: {emailAddresss=null, firstName=null, lastName=null}

WARN [https-jsse-nio-9595-exec-1][code_jsp:173] {code="400", msg="", uri=/c/portal/login/openidconnect} javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
```

As I understand, it didnt get valid profile information such email, name even I did include profile and email in scope and that lead to unable to create user and then cannot redirect to login state page.

And as I read in ADFS 2016 FAQ that the profile and scope is no longer supported, that means claims for email and profile cannot be called. There is also an article in ADFS 2016 FAQ that tells to customize custom id token in ADFS which requires to implement code in Visual Studio.

I am looking for a way to fix the above errors or a new way to implement openid connect in liferay by coding.

Comment: I have experience with ADFS, but not with liferay. 

From what i understand, you want ADFS to create claims for the email, firstname and lastname attributes. Could you show your Issuance Transform rules configured in ADFS? Also, have you tried checking the option "allatclaims" in the Client Permissions tab?

Excuse me if i understood your question incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, i want ADFS to create claims for the email, firstname and lastname attributes. About the allatclaims, i already tried (added it in the scope) but it returned the same result. About the ADFS, i cannot get access directly cause company configured it and it has been used well with other services.

Comment: @SylveKK did you manage to solve this issue? I am facing this issue now. could you please advise your observation or configuration. Thanks